# Tying to add a variable to a state using hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am not able to add imageData to my state variable

```js
setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, imageData: source.uri }));

const [autoData, setValues] = useState(state);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create and add status variables as objects.

```js
  const updateField = e => {
    setValues({
      ...autoData,
      [imageData]: e.value
    });
  };

  const [autoData, setValues] = useState({});
```